# How to set the maxidletimems for Mongoengine

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine

The mongo library used in my project is Mongoengine

I often find the error 'pymongo. errors. CursorNotFound: Cursor not found' in the logs. After investigation, it was found that the mongo server actively closed the spatial link, and this error occurred when the link was used again. But I couldn't find an introduction to setting "maxIdleTimeMS" in the Mongoengine related documents.

Can someone help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the information [here](https://github.com/MongoEngine/flask-mongoengine/blob/master/flask_mongoengine/connection.py#L30). You can setting maxIdleTimeMS by config `MONGODB_MAXIDLETIMEMS`. if you use `MONGODB_SETTINGS`, you would use `maxidletimems`

Example:

```
MONGODB_SETTINGS = {
    "db": os.getenv("MONGODB_DATABASE", "test"),
    "host": os.getenv(
        "MONGODB_URI",
        "mongodb://test:test@127.0.0.1:27017/test?replicaSet=rs0",
    ),
    "maxidletimems": int(os.getenv("MONGODB_MAXIDLETIMEMS", "12000"))
}
```